# Where does the localhost port number come from when a file is opened in the browser from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, localhost

If I open an index.html file in VS2013 and the file is located on my C: my URL is localhost:496989/index.html

If I have the file located on my E: the port number is different

How does the port number get determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are randomly assigned when you create a new web site or web application.

The port number is stored within the project e.g.

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebSite1\.vs\config\applicationhost.config
```

or in the main config file for IIS Express:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
```

this config file is passed to IIS Express when opening the site in Visual Studio

I looked at this in 2015 but I think it is the same in 2013.

Comment: What if there is no applicationhost.config file? As in an angularjs project that just has html, javascript and css

Comment: If you run it in IIS or IIS Express there is always an applicationhost.config file. You can use Process Explorer to see the command line IIS Express was started with, it should have a /config parameter pointing the the config file.

Comment: Process explorer? Do you mean this link? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx  Also how do I tell whether I am running it in IIS or IIS Express?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Run it and start your web site, find iisexpress.exe and double-click it. On the `Image` tab look at the `Command line` field.

Comment: I downloaded and ran Process Explorer and found iisexpress.exe, but the command line in the image tab is blank. The path in the same tab states "Error opening process"

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio as elevated administrator? If so you have to run Process Explorer as admin too. For normal web development you should run VS as standard user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84909/discussion-between-kirsten-g-and-peter-hahndorf).